# How to find how many permutations of number(string S) without leading zeroes are divisible by 11, without using brute-force?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

Suppose you have a string **S = {2,0,9,0}**. The values that meet the conditions are **2009**,
**2090**, **2900**, **9002**, **9020** and **9200** (all permutations of S = {2,0,9,0}). Among those, only 2090 and 9020 satisfy the second condition (divisible by 11), so the answer for S = {2,0,9,0} is **2**.

What if the string S can go up to 100 digits? Brute force would never end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, it ends in a 1, there's one digit less to do.

Comment: Hint: 100 equals 1 (mod 11).

Comment: What?  1 % 11 != 100.  1 % 11 == 1.  [Proof](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%25+11)

Comment: I think he meant (100 % 11) == 1

Comment: Ah.  So I did.  I'm not sure how that's useful, though...

Comment: so why aren't 0209 (11*19) and 0902 (11*82) acceptable?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: without leading zeroes.

Comment: A number is divisible by 11 if the sum of the odd digits minus the sum of the even digits is divisible by 11. This may help divide-and-conquering the problem.

Comment: What about 77? 14 isn't divisible by 11

Comment: @BrianGradin: He means the sum of the digits in the odd or even *positions*.

Comment: Wait, you mean the odd digits as in odd indices, as if the number was stored in an array?

Comment: Search for a Big Number library or implement your own division / modulo function.

Comment: Don't forget to give credit to StackOverflow when you submit your program to whatever contest you're entering.

Comment: This is a problem from a past contest. Here's the link: http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=602&page=show_problem&problem=4410

Answer (score 2):

By brute fore, there are n! strings to consider.

If we notice that all that matters about a digit is whether it is in an odd or even position, that reduces it to n!/(n/2)!<sup>2</sup>.

Then we remember that there aren't very many possible digits. We can count how many of each numeral there are, then all we have to do is iterate over all possible partitions of each into two bins (odd and even positions). This is costly, but not totally intractable.

If the strings were really big, thousands of digits, then it would be worth considering the fact that 11 of the same digit in either bin is equivalent to nothing, but for only 100 digits it's probably not worth the effort.

Once we verify that a certain partition corresponds to numbers that are divisible by eleven, we can count how many ways to arrange all of the digits in one bin into all the available positions, which is O(1).